# Command pattern with parameters and value return

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I'm interested if using a Command pattern has sense if you need that command returns a value and has parameters? As defined, ICommand should have an void Execute() method, and the case that I'm interested in is stepping a bit from that? Thank you.

Comment: Design patterns are guidelines, not blueprints.

Comment: So, it is natural if I, let's say, add properties like Params and Result to ICommand interface? It doesn't mean that I'm breaking some concept, or something like that?

Comment: @Servy No to my first, or my second question?

Comment: @breakpoint To the second.

Comment: C# supports closures, lambdas, delegates, functions as first class values etc. C# has absolutely no use for the GoF definition of the Command Pattern. Take advantage of C#'s support for passing around references to functions and be happy that doing so is a valid example of the Command Pattern.

Comment: Ok, thanks to you both.

Comment: @DavidArno So, you are saying that I should, in cases where Command pattern is needed, try to use some of the concepts that are already implemented in the language? But what if you are working with an WPF app, aren't there Commands one of the main principles used? Sorry if that is not correct, I haven't really studied WPF that much, I'm trying to get this pattern because of that, also.

Comment: @breakpoint 1. Yes, always make use of language features when implementing patterns. 2. Be careful of the overloading of terms in patterns. I'm not familiar with WPF either, but if I may use an example I'm more familiar with, consider ASP.NET MVC. The Model-View-Controller (MVC) pattern has controllers, but they are not examples of the Control pattern. I'd guess that WPF Controllers are the same. At the risk of blowing my own trumpet, you might like to read a blog I wrote on the subject: http://www.davidarno.org/2013/06/17/are-design-patterns-compatible-with-modern-software-techniques/

Comment: @breakpoint Incidentally, whilst this question isn't really in keeping with SO guidelines on questions, I'm impressed with the way you have sought clarification from commentators. So have a +1 from me for that ;)

Comment: Thank you Sir, and I will sure visit your blog!